# Remove function and its definition from python code

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

For example: **old file**

```
def MyFunction():

       some code inside MyFunction()

def MyFunction1():

       some code inside MyFunction1()

if __name__ == "__main__":

       some code inside
```

**New  file**

```
def MyFunction1():

       some code inside MyFunction1()

if __name__ == "__main__":

       some code inside
```

I want to remove **MyFunction()** and code inside it from multiple files
and **MyFunction()** is not followed by **MyFunction1()  . MyFunction()** Could be located any where in the code followed by any code.

Comment: hi Sundeep there are 2 function MyFunction() and MyFunction1() and following by some indented code i want to remove MyFunction and the indented code in it from my file.And keep Myfunction1() and the remaning indented code in it

Comment: please click https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/426865/edit and add those details.. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help for formatting help... also add what you've tried..

Comment: The line immediately after the `def` line does not seem to be indented. Do you want to remove empty lines too?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^[[:alpha:]]/         { del=0 }
     /^def MyFunction\(\):/ { del=1 }
     del == 0' file.py
```

This `awk` program will pass through everything as long as the variable `del` is set to zero.

The variable gets set to 1 if the first line of the definition of `MyFunction()` is found, and then reset to zero when a line with an alphabetic character in the beginning of the line is found.

This deletes the `MyFunction()` definition from the input file.

The result when running this on the example data is

```
def MyFunction1():

       some code inside MyFunction1()

if __name__ == "__main__":

       some code inside
```